# Suggestion for Matrix Table representaton in SQL Server Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix

Would like to get some suggestions on how to represent the following Matrix in an SQL Table like representation. Thinking of a three table structure like the following

Catid,CatName

LevelId,LevelName

Catid,MinValue,Maxvalue,LevelId

Any Suggestions? The idea is to get information about the level of approval required based on the Amount.

[image]